# Lines animation

Tags: c#, winforms

Need to create an animation that will be activated when you click on the `button`. I just want the usual animation on the edges of the `form`. `Button1` - two running strips on the left and right going to the bottom. `Button2` - two running stripes left and right going up. I really need this, but I do not know how to do it. Below is an example of what I need, but this animation creates a running strip on top of the program.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer tmr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDoubleClick += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 10;
        tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
    }

    int x;
    int step = 5; 
    void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        x = 0;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += step;
        if (x > this.Width)
        {
            x = 0;
            (sender as Timer).Stop();
        }
        this.Invalidate();  
    }
    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, x, 4);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post an image demonstrating the effect? I'm having a hard time picturing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Quite difficult to understand what you want, but if i understood you correctly:

```
  void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
     using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 4)){
        e.Graphics.drawLine(pen, 0, 0, 0, x);
        e.Graphics.drawLine(pen, Width, x, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

I typed it without IDE, to there may be typos. fix it yourself :)

Most displays run on 60hz, which is ~17ms per frame so you should update it every 17ms or even better - according to display refresh rate

But there is a problem: "Timer" does not have that high resolution. In my case - it can refresh only every ~30ms. 
(Last night i found this out. And i guess today ill have to make my own version of timer)

Here is my mini library https://github.com/WithoutCaps/LimitlessUI  the things that you are intrested are: AnimationTimer_WOC, Animator_WOC, MaterialTextBox_WOC (definetely check this out) and DropDown_WOC